# Jax installation on gpu

Tags: python, development-environment, jax

I'm trying to reproduce the result of the s5 model https://github.com/lindermanlab/S5. But I ran into a major issue with installing jax. The authors provided a requirements_gpu.txt:

```
flax
torch
torchtext
tensorflow-datasets==4.5.2
pydub==0.25.1
datasets
tqdm
--find-links https://storage.googleapis.com/jax-releases/jax_releases.html
jax[cuda]>=version
```

This will cause

```
from jax import linear_util as lu
ImportError: cannot import name 'linear_util' from 'jax'
```

I've also tried to directly install jax like on the official guide page https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

But still, lots of errors occur. I tried downgrading/upgrading my Python and using a different gpu(4090 with cuda12.3, 3060 with cuda11.4, and 2060 with cuda11.1)
They all didn't work :-(

These are the places where the authors imported jax

```
from jax import random
import jax.numpy as np
from jax.scipy.linalg import block_diag
import jax
from jax.nn import one_hot
from flax.training import train_state
from flax import linen as nn
from jax.nn.initializers import lecun_normal, normal
from jax import random
from jax.numpy.linalg import eigh
from flax import linen as nn
```

My current environment has

```
absl-py==1.4.0
aiohttp==3.9.3
aiosignal==1.3.1
async-timeout==4.0.3
attrs==23.2.0
certifi==2024.2.2
charset-normalizer==3.3.2
chex==0.1.6
colorama==0.4.6
commonmark==0.9.1
contourpy==1.2.0
cycler==0.12.1
datasets==2.18.0
dill==0.3.8
dm-tree==0.1.8
etils==1.7.0
filelock==3.13.1
flax==0.4.0
fonttools==4.50.0
frozenlist==1.4.1
fsspec==2024.2.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.63.0
grpcio==1.62.1
huggingface-hub==0.21.4
idna==3.6
importlib_resources==6.4.0
jax==0.2.22
jaxlib==0.4.13
Jinja2==3.1.3
joblib==1.3.2
kiwisolver==1.4.5
Markdown==3.6
MarkupSafe==2.1.5
matplotlib==3.8.3
ml-dtypes==0.3.2
mpmath==1.3.0
msgpack==1.0.8
multidict==6.0.5
multiprocess==0.70.16
nest-asyncio==1.6.0
networkx==3.2.1
numpy==1.26.4
nvidia-cublas-cu12==12.1.3.1
nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu12==12.1.105
nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu12==12.1.105
nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu12==12.1.105
nvidia-cudnn-cu12==8.9.2.26
nvidia-cufft-cu12==11.0.2.54
nvidia-curand-cu12==10.3.2.106
nvidia-cusolver-cu12==11.4.5.107
nvidia-cusparse-cu12==12.1.0.106
nvidia-nccl-cu12==2.19.3
nvidia-nvjitlink-cu12==12.4.99
nvidia-nvtx-cu12==12.1.105
opt-einsum==3.3.0
optax==0.1.7
orbax-checkpoint==0.5.7
packaging==24.0
pandas==2.2.1
pillow==10.2.0
promise==2.3
protobuf==3.20.3
pyarrow==15.0.2
pyarrow-hotfix==0.6
pydub==0.25.1
Pygments==2.17.2
pyparsing==3.1.2
python-dateutil==2.9.0.post0
pytz==2024.1
PyYAML==6.0.1
requests==2.31.0
rich==11.2.0
scikit-learn==1.4.1.post1
scipy==1.12.0
six==1.16.0
sympy==1.12
tensorboard==2.16.2
tensorboard-data-server==0.7.2
tensorflow-datasets==4.5.2
tensorflow-metadata==1.14.0
tensorstore==0.1.56
termcolor==2.4.0
threadpoolctl==3.4.0
toolz==0.12.1
torch==2.2.1
torchdata==0.7.1
torchtext==0.17.1
torchvision==0.17.1
tqdm==4.66.2
triton==2.2.0
typing_extensions==4.10.0
tzdata==2024.1
urllib3==2.2.1
Werkzeug==3.0.1
xxhash==3.4.1
yarl==1.9.4
zipp==3.18.1
```

As I said, we have three types of gpus on the cluster: 4090 with cuda12.3, 3060 with cuda 11.4, and 2060 with cuda 11.1. I'm wondering if anyone could please tell me the version of jax ,jaxlib , and flax that will work on at least one of these three machines. Thank you so much for the help. Please kindly inform me if you need any further information.

Comment: "But still, lots of errors occur." That is very unspecific. What are they saying?

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I said that simply because I tried too many things, most of them even I cannot replicate the errors :-( But I remember there was Attribute error:  jax.numpy' has no attribute 'devicearray'.